# remote filtering

Tags: extjs

i have added filter to each of the columns in a grid panel. When i try to query an item it filters the items based on the page displayed rather than the total number of records becuase i enabled paging.

Can you please help me by giving the basic idea as how to do remote filtering with paging grid.what are the parameters that are needed to send to server side in order to do remote filtering

Thanks.

Comment: iam sorry but iam not aware of it..i dint know that we have to check the check mark if the answer is right..sure from next time i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the filter is executed you'll need to re-execute your remote query and repopulate the grid's store.  There's really no getting around that.  The simple approach would be to simply execute the query and reload the grid from scratch to page 1 (with the default params).  You could also get fancy and try to preserve the current page, but that will get tricky since values on the current page may have gotten filtered out of the view, so you'll have to programmatically determine how to "shift" your paging to stay on page X with a full page of data.  Also, page X may no longer even exist if the filter results in fewer pages than X.

In my opinion, when filtering remotely it's usually not worth it to try and preserve the current paging state, but it's up to you and your requirements.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to send the filter information to server side.. By giving var local = false; and in the var filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({ e encode: encode, local: false,  filters: [{ dataIndex: 'InScope', type: 'string' } ] }); how do send the text entered to server side ?

Comment: how can we send field, type, value parameters to server side.